# BIND Server problem in Fedora

Tags: fedora, dns

I am install the  Bind Server in Fedora Linux.I configured the named.conf file.However,
When I run "service named start" command,I am receive the following error.

```
starting named: /usr/sbin/named: symbol lookup error: 
/usr/sbin/named: undefined    symbol:isc_stats_dump
```

What can happen?

Here is my the  named.conf file.

```
// named.conf
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory "/var/named";
    dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query { localhost; };
    recursion yes;
};

logging {
    channel default_debug {
        file "data/named.run";
        severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";

zone "ilker.net." {
    type master;
    allow-query { any; };
    file "/var/named/ilker.net";
};
```

I created the a file called ilker.net in the /var/named folder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have wrong/damaged version of bind-lib.

Run `yum upgrade bind-lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes for solution maybe you binds rpm packet corrupted or bug problem reasons..

```
[root@server var]# cp /etc/named.conf /root/

[root@server var]# cp -apfr /var/named/ /root/

[root@server var]# /scripts/ensurerpm bind-*
```